# Spark Hive: temporary table disappear within session

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, temporary

I create a couple of temporary tables using

```
hive.executeUpdate("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT ...")
```

in Hive from Spark.
I check all tables with

```
hive.showTables().show()
```

in the session between each query I perform later (all like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`) and the temporary tables are being dropped unpredictably.

This is not happening in HiveQL.

Anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your api, I think you are using [hortonworks-spark](/questions/tagged/hortonworks-spark) connector

**you have to prefix your table with databaseschema.table all over.**

or set the database like this.

```
hive.setDatabase("default")
```

then your CTAS

```
hive.executeUpdate("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT ...")
```

for example:

```
val sql =  s"create temporary table $tmpTableName like $dbName.$tabName "
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...)
```

what ever you want to do.

> Q: This is not happening in HiveQL.
>   Anyone had similar issues?

In hiveql you will use the same database schema thats the reason its working as expected.

Comment: is it not the case with you ?